# I'm unable to convert ip in array to longitude and latitude

Tags: php, codeigniter, geolite2

I'm trying to process an array ip from data posted from a input post. To convert this to latitude longitude I am using the following code,

**this my ci library:**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  include APPPATH . 'libraries/GeoIP/src/geoipcity.inc';

    class GeoIp{

        public function info($ip){
            $gi = geoip_open(APPPATH . 'libraries/GeoIp/data/GeoLiteCity.dat', GEOIP_STANDARD);
            $record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, $ip);
            geoip_close($gi);
            return $record;
        }

        public function get($ip){
            $gi = geoip_open(APPPATH . 'libraries/GeoIp/data/GeoLiteCity.dat', GEOIP_STANDARD);
            $records = array();
            $ips = is_array($ip);
            foreach ($ips as $key=>$value) {
                $records[] = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, $value);
            }

            foreach ($records as $record) {
            $record_string = $record->longitude . "," . $record->latitude;
            geoip_close($gi);
            return $record_string;
            }
        }

    }
```

**and this my controller:**

```
public function iplat(){
    $this->load->library('geoip');
    $record = $this->geoip->get($this->input->post('ip'));

    echo json_encode($record);


}
```

This code always returns null

Comment: 2 problem seems to me :- 1. `$gi = geoip_open(APPPATH . 'libraries/GeoIp/data/GeoLiteCity.dat', GEOIP_STANDARD);` i think path issue is there.2. ` $this->load->library('geoip');` you need to cehck that it is working fine or not. check your error log files for that.(I hope codeignitor produces error log files somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see right away is your code

```
        $ips = is_array($ip);
        foreach ($ips as $key=>$value) {
            $records[] = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, $value);
        }
```

Beacuse you have assigned `is_array($ip)` to `$ips`, `$ips` is now a boolean and not and array. So you cannot run a loop on it. Perhaps you meant to run the loop of `$ip` like this:

```
if(is_array($id))
{
    foreach ($ip as $key=>$value)
    {
        $records[] = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, $value);
    }
}
```